# Cannot use empty object or column names. Use a single space if necessary

Tags: c#, sql, dataset

In this code:

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM rd_main WHERE manifest!=\"\" AND manifest IS NOT NULL";
string tableName = "rd_main";
conn.Open();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds, tableName);
```

I keep getting:

```
Cannot use empty object or column names. Use a single space if necessary.
```

on the da.Fill(...)

I have tried:

```
SELECT rd_main.* FROM rd_main WHERE rd_main.manifest<>"" AND rd_main.manifest IS NOT NULL
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want single quotes, not double quotes.

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM rd_main WHERE manifest!='' AND manifest IS NOT NULL";
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM rd_main WHERE manifest!='' AND manifest IS NOT NULL